# PHP 'IF/ELSE' result position

Tags: php, html, css

I am creating a basic web application on ATOM which consists of the user having to sign in. The sign in functionality is working fine, however, my IF/Else statement (below) prints a message if the user has entered incorrect login information.

IF/ElSE

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
  header("Location: home.php");
}
else{
  echo ' <font color=red> <h2>Incorrect username/password</h2> </font>';
}
```

Login code

```
*<body>
<div id="frm">
  <form id="login-form" name="login-form" method="post"  role="form">
    <p>
      <label>Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Password : </label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" id="login_btn" value="Login" />
    </p>
</form>
```

*

I have tried a number of different things, such as trying to create a tag and link it within the HTML but to no avail. Here is what I currently have at the moment.

[image: Current login screen]

My question is, is it at all possible to display this inside the login box without changing the code too much? Couldn't find any related articles that helps with this.

Comment: yes. just set a flag like `$login_success = false;` plus a message var like `$error_msg = "Incorrect...";` and show that inside the login box if it's set.

Comment: he needs to post his code, for this login box, we don't know what he has at the moment, thats why he is getting downvoted, he only posted a screenshot, but not the code relating to that screenshot

Comment: Hi @KebabProgrammer, apologies, posted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for you. You can simply use the $_SESSION to store information (in variables) across multiple pages.

it will look something like this:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
  header("Location: home.php");
}
else{
  $_SESSION['message'] = "Incorrect username/password.";
}
```

And then in your HTML file you can put this anywhere you want inside your login box:

```
<div id="frm">
  <form id="login-form" name="login-form" method="post"  role="form">
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['message']) )
    {
       echo $_SESSION['message'];

       unset($_SESSION['message']);
    }?>
    <p>
      <label>Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Password : </label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" id="login_btn" value="Login" />
    </p>
</form>
```